# How to create a builtin file and folder in custom eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse plugin which need to be shipped with builtin ant build file. Its working when I am running the project. However, when I am exporting the plugin and deploying the exported plugin in another eclipse, the ant build file is not getting generated. My suspect is that in the runtime, the source of the ant build file is not accessed. Any pointer how to solve the issue? Here is the code :

```java
private void createAntFile(IProject project, Properties properties) throws     CoreException, IOException {         
    InputStream antFileInputStream =null;       
    try {           
        String antFileName = properties.getProperty("name.ant.file");
        String antFilePath = properties.getProperty("path.ant.file");
        IFile file = project.getFile(antFileName);          
        antFileInputStream = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry(antFilePath).openStream();         
        file.create(antFileInputStream, false, null);   
        antFileInputStream.close();         
    }finally{           
        if(antFileInputStream!=null){
            try {
                antFileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
name.ant.file=build.xml
path.ant.file=src/weblogic/ant/build.xml
```

The source build file I am hard coding in the path src/weblogic/ant/build.xml

Edit:

Here is the code to create builtin folders:

```
private void createWeblogicTemplate(IProject project, Properties properties) throws IOException, CoreException {        
    String weblogicTemplateSourcePath = properties.getProperty("path.weblogic.template.source");
    Path path = new Path(weblogicTemplateSourcePath);
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID);        
    URL fileURL = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
    String filePath = FileLocator.resolve(fileURL).getPath();
    System.out.println(filePath);
    File sourceFile = new File(filePath);
    String weblogicTemplateTargetPath = properties.getProperty("path.weblogic.template.target");
    IFolder folder = project.getFolder(weblogicTemplateTargetPath); 
    copyFolder(sourceFile,folder,project,properties);           
}
```

The line System.out.println(filePath) is printing path as 
/C:/Users//Desktop/eclipse-rcp-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/../../../workspace-plugin/weblogic/resources/weblogictemplate/

So, locally its working. However, its not working when I deploy the pluin in some other eclipse. Any pointer how to create builtin folders?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be expecting the `src/weblogic/ant/` directory to be included in the exported plugin jar - the src directory is not normally included in the plugin jar.

Put resources you want to include in the plugin in a separate directory (such as `resources`) and include that directory in the plugin `build.properties` so that it is included in the exported plugin jar.

Comment: When I have moved the build.xml to resources folder, its working fine. However, I need to put more folders such as jdbc template, security folder etc. in the resources. Those folders are not getting created. Do I need to do something extra to copy folders?

Comment: Your code is only creating the build.xml file, you will have to write code to create all files and folders you need.